# Excel from email inbox to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have to import data from Excel into a SQL Server database.

I am getting Excel files via email daily. I have to get them out from email and put the contents into the database. Also, I want to automate it instead of doing it manually.

I am thinking of below ideas:

1. Fetching the email attachment out of the inbox (automated process using some tool etc.) and save it to say the `O:` drive (then it's simple to pull into the database from there)
2. Taking help of any tool available (open source) and get the Excel content into SQL Server directly from the inbox.

I hope that makes sense about what I am trying to do.

Can someone please tell me how to automate this?

Thanks,
AP

Comment: a windows service can run on an automated schedule to read items from the inbox. No need to save them anywhere else, just load the data into objects in your code and then directly import to the DB all in the same process. It's possible even you could just use a SQL agent job to automate, and use a SSIS package to do the import, pretty sure that could read from Excel. Done any research yet?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to auto save attachments. And yes, after you do that you can bulk import your data with an Agent Job and a schedule of your choosing. If you have a *specific* issue then let us know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use VBA for everything here.

1)  Download attachments from Outlook.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "C:\Users\DT168\Documents\outlook-attachments\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

2)  Load data from Excel file(s) into SQL Server.

```
Sub InsertARecord()
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim stCon As String, stSQL As String
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

stCon = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=JOEY"
cnt.ConnectionString = stCon
stSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTable (FieldNames)"
stSQL = stSQL & "VALUES (ActualValues)"
stSQL = stSQL & "WHERE lockStatus = 'nolock'"

cnt.Open
rst.Open stSQL, cnt, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also, see this URL.

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#Introduction

Comment: Hi! If I may ask, where should one place the code from section 2 above? Would be be included as part of the event triggered by the incoming email (so in Outlook's script)?

Comment: It runs in a Module in Excel. https://www.emagenit.com/VBA%20Folder/what_is_a_vba_module.htm

Comment: Yes, I meant should it be placed into the same VBA script as the "download the file" function. I'm going to proceed as if that is so. Another question, how are you composing "stSQL = stSQL & "VALUES (ActualValues)"" Are you assuming that there is code that converts the rows from the Excel file into a big string, or is there some specific way not specified here that one can populate "ActualValues" from a file with x rows?

Comment: Replace FieldNames with your actual field names. Try the code with a small and simple example. Get that working, and then you can expand to more complex scenarios.

Comment: Sorry -- I had to halt this part of the project. For various reasons, the VBA to download the files would just stop (possibly because of settings outside of my control?). Even when I told Outlook to Enable macros, it might work for a day or two or a week, but eventually, it would just stop working, even if I left the computer on an Outlook running. If I can't get this thing to reliably run the macro and save the file, then I can't reliably count on it to do anything downstream. :(